# replaced Fragment can't load data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

the first time to replace and load fragment data is fine.but replace the fragment again, the new fragment can't load data.

for example if the fragment have a button, click it will show an invisible textView. the first fragment can show the textView,but replace to the second fragment(same code) can't show it.

```
private void startHomeFragment() {
    mDiscoveryFragment = new AskQuestionFragment();
    beginTransaction(FirsthomeFragment);
}

private void beginTransaction(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
}


public void onItemChanged(int index) {
    switch (index) {
        case replace to the second:
            SecondFragment secondFragment= new secondFragment;
            beginTransaction(secondFragment);
            break;
```

Comment: Load the data in the onCreateView() method

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, can you post more code to make it clearer? Also your switch statement in `onItemChanged` won't work. You are switching on an `int` then doing `case replace to the second:` it should be something like `case 0:` or `case 1` etc. depending on what you want to do